# Jquery mobile remove extra padding from grid with bold contents

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have a grid in a jquery mobile site, and every second row has a background colour to make it more user friendly. All the content of `ui-block-a` has `font-weight: bold;` from my css, and as a result there is extra padding at the bottom of the cell like so:

[image: extra padding]

This looks really bad, so how do I remove it? I have tried putting in `padding-bottom = 0px;` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to set a minimum height of 20px for my coloured in div class

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,

```
.ui-block-a {
    padding-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

`!important` will override `JM` css

Comment: Preferably never override the base classes directly, create another class and change the padding in that class.